# I don't understand 3.4/2 in the Standard

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, name-lookup, qualified-name

I don't understand 3.4/2 in the Standard:

> A name “looked up in the context of an expression” is looked up as an
>   unqualified name in the scope where the expression is found.

What if the name is qualified, as `N::i` below?

```
#include <iostream>

namespace N { int i = 1; }

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    std::cout << N::i << '\n';
}
```

The qualified name `N::i` is not looked up in the scope where `N::i` is found, i.e., it's not looked up in the scope of main() and the global scope!

Comment: 3.4/2 is the definition of what "looked up in the context of an expression" means. It does not require lookup of all names in the context of the expression they appear in. "looked up in the context of an expression" is one lookup mechanism; other lookup mechanisms are qualified lookup and ADL.

Comment: Since the name is qualified, it's looked up by the rules in [basic.lookup.qual] (§3.4.3).

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comment by @JerryCoffin, the rules for qualified lookup are:

**3.4.3 Qualiﬁed name lookup [basic.lookup.qual]**

> 3 In a declaration in which the declarator-id is a qualiﬁed-id, names
>   used before the qualiﬁed-id being declared are looked up in the
>   deﬁning namespace scope; names following the qualiﬁed-id are looked up
>   in the scope of the member’s class or namespace.

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct N { enum { i = 1 }; };

int main()
{
    std::cout << N::i << '\n'; // prints 1

    struct N { enum { i = 0 }; };

    std::cout << N::i << '\n'; // prints 0
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/220317a58490b37b).

Comment: There's no declaration of a qualified-id there. That rule implements how, for example, a member function declaration can declare parameters of member type, without repeating the qualification for every parameter.

Answer (score 0):

First the left-hand side of `::` is looked up, and then the right-hand side is looked up inside it. So, to look up `N::i`, first it finds `N` using unqualified lookup, then it looks inside `N` to find `i`. Simple!

In your example, you redefine `N` locally. After the local definition, the outer definition is hidden per §3.3.10: *"A name can be hidden by an explicit declaration of that same name in a nested declarative region or derived class."*

Since the compiler knows at the outset that the left-hand side (`N`) must yield a type, namespace, or enumeration, any other lookup results (i.e. functions, variables, and templates) are ignored. So, you could also do:

```
#include <iostream>

struct N { enum { i = 1 }; };

int main()
{
    int N = 3;
    std::cout << N::i << '\n'; // prints 1
    std::cout << N << '\n'; // prints 3

    struct N { enum { i = 0 }; };

    std::cout << N::i << '\n'; // prints 0
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a7c9e34b1e74ce7

See §3.4.3/1:

> The name of a class or namespace member or enumerator can be referred to after the `::` scope resolution operator (5.1) applied to a nested-name-specifier that denotes its class, namespace, or enumeration. If a `::` scope resolution operator in a nested-name-specifier is not preceded by a decltype-specifier, lookup of the name preceding that `::` considers only namespaces, types, and templates whose specializations are types. If the name found does not designate a namespace or a class, enumeration, or dependent type, the program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

As dyp explained in the comments, that paragraph simply explains what it means when a name is looked up in the context of an expression. It's not trying to say that every name is looked up in the context of an expression. As such, in order to understand how name lookup works for `N::i`, you have to consult the appropriate section of the standard—which might or might not tell you to look up the name in the context of some expression.

According to C++11 [expr.prim.general]/9:

> A `::`, or a *nested-name-specifier* that names a namespace (7.3), in either case followed by the name of a member of that namespace (or the name of a member of a namespace made visible by a *using-directive*) is a
> *qualified-id*; 3.4.3.2 describes name lookup for namespace members that appear in qualified-ids. The result
> is the member. The type of the result is the type of the member. The result is an lvalue if the member is a
> function or a variable and a prvalue otherwise.

3.4.3.2 [namespace.qual] explains further:

> If the *nested-name-specifier* of a *qualified-id* nominates a namespace, the name specified after the *nested-name-specifier* is looked up in the scope of the namespace. [...]

There's more, but it's not relevant.

Note that this is a bit circular. What [namespace.qual]/1 should really say is that when you have something that *looks* like a *qualified-id* because it's a *nested-name-specifier* naming a namespace followed by an identifier (or something else that can be an *unqualified-id*), you look up the name after the *nested-name-specifier* and only if that succeeds, the whole thing is a *qualified-id*.

Anyway, the point is that "looked up in the context of an expression" is irrelevant in this particular example.